# .bashrc alias help command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to create a custom help command for my .bashrc aliases heres what I have so far

this is my custom script so far

```
bashrc='/home/jordan/.bashrc'

alias=$(cat $bashrc | grep -o -P '(?<=alias ).*(?==)' | sed -e 's/ //g' | sed -e "s/ls='ls--color//g")
desc=$(cat $bashrc | grep -o -P '(?=#Custom).*' | sed -e 's/#Custom //g')
```

This is my .bashrc aliases

```
alias ci3='code ~/.config/i3/config && exit' #Custom Open i3 config in VS Code
alias cpoly='code ~/.config/polybar/config && exit' #Custom Open i3 Config in VS Code
alias cdpoly='code ~/.config/polybar/launch.sh && exit' #Custom Open Polybar Config in VS Code
alias cds='cd ~/.config/scripts' #Custom cd into the scripts directery
alias cdc='cd ~/.config' #Custom cd into ~/.config
alias cbash='code ~/.bashrc' #Custom open .bashrc in VS Code
alias vg='cd ~/voxelgame' #Custom cd into voxel game directory
alias sb='source ~/.bashrc && echo ".bashrc compiled"' #Custom Compile .bashrc
alias update-addons='sudo python3 $HOME/Documents/wow-addon-updater/WoWAddonUpdater.py' #Custom update elvui
alias cdd='cd ~/Documents' #Custom cd into Documents
alias school='cd ~/Documents/School' #Custom cd into School directory
alias cs105='cd ~/Documents/CS105' #Custom cd into CS105 directory
alias cs140='cd ~/Documents/CS140' #Custom cd into CS140 directory
alias math137='cd ~/Documents/MATH137' #Custom cd into MATH137 directory
alias cs105t='evince ~/Documents/School/CS105/Big-Java-Early-Objects.pdf &' #Custom Open CS105 Textbook in Evince(PDF Viewer)
alias math137t='evince ~/Documents/School/MATH137/Precalculus-OP.pdf &' #Custom Open MATH137 Textbook in Evince(PDF Viewer)
```

edit: I want the command to be a sort of custom help page that lists the commands and what they do.

Comment: what do you want your custom help command to do? be specific

Comment: Haha forgot to include that part, I wanted to create a help page for all my aliases so if I foget what they do I can just type a command to get a list of them and what they do. Thats why i've commented them the way I did

Comment: You should show the exact output you want.

Comment: `alias` will print out all your aliases. do you specifically need the comments?

Comment: BTW, consider `vg() { : 'cd into voxel game directory'; cd ~/voxelgame; 
}` as a function definition instead of an alias; that way using `declare -f` to list the functions will give you the comments as well (since they're being passed as arguments to `:`, and thus part of the body text).

Comment: ...that said, "please write a script for me that does X" isn't generally inside StackOverflow's scope. If you have a *specific question* about what your script is doing, could you make it more explicit? Really, though, just using the `alias` command to list aliases makes much more sense. (It's also noteworthy that functions carry metadata about which file and line they came from, whereas aliases don't have any of that state).

Comment: How about just `grep '^alias' ~/.bashrc` to show the full line from `.bashrc`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alias xyz='echo "hi"; #does things'
alias
```

will output

```
alias xyz='echo "hi"; #does things'
```

and

```
xyz
```

will run the command and output

```
hi
```

You would have to change your aliases to include the comments, but it wouldn't impact their output. is this sufficient?

Comment: This would be a problem if the alias is supposed to take arguments, such as `alias sl='ls # autofix typo'` would no longer allow `sl -l`. One possible hack would be ``alias sl='ls `#autofix typo` '``